# How to make a single GhostScript call to do conversion, compression, and cropping?

Tags: ghostscript

I am using TeXLive 2010 and do my job using the following workflow with 6 steps. I want to reduce the number of steps as minimal as possible because I will apply the workflow to the web based system.

1. `latex %1`
2. `dvips %1`
3. `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps`
4. `gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=%1-temp.pdf %1.pdf`
5. `pdfcrop --hires %1-temp.pdf %1.pdf`
6. `pdftops -eps %1.pdf`

I know that the steps 3, 4 and 5 internally invoke GhostScript. Shortly speaking, how to combine them into a single GhostScript call?

### My current effort

I have tried to combine the step 3 and 4 as follows and it works.

1. `latex %1`
2. `dvips %1`
3. `ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps`
4. `rename %1.pdf %1-temp.pdf`
5. `pdfcrop --hires %1-temp.pdf %1.pdf`
6. `pdftops -eps %1.pdf`

And I am still interested in combining steps 3 and 5 above.

Comment: Why don't you use a small bash-script or a makefile? Then the number of steps are irrelevant.

Comment: @Marco: The above steps are extracted from my batch file. :-) You can see there are `%1` placeholders that represent the file name without extension.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought it was an example ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine steps 3 and 5. Steps 3&4 use `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite` so they can combine. Step 5 uses `-sDEVICE=bbox` to find the bbox. You need separate runs of gs to use separate devices.

You can eliminate your revised step 4 with the `rename %1.pdf %1-temp.pdf` by making step 3 as `ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps %1-temp.pdf`. By the way I needed to change `=` to `#` for `-dCompatibilityLevel#1.5`.

It's not worth trying to optimize this further. If you are planning to run this on a web system on user-supplied code then be aware of all the security risks. You better add `-R` to `dvips`, and be aware that `pdfcrop` executes `pdftex` internally (`pdfcrop --restricted` helps a little) and so on.

Comment: As `pdfcrop` executes `pdftex` internally, do we need to pass `-interaction=nonstopmode` to `pdfcrop`?

Comment: No. Not necessary.